# Can we write trigger in MS SQL for .mdf File

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, triggers, mdf

I am making windows based application, in which i have taken MS SQL as the Database. now i have taken the .mdf file, and have attached that with .Net so can i write trigger for this database ?

Comment: What do you want the trigger to do?

Comment: the question is not clear. Do you want to write triggers in Visual stuio IDE?